# Polymer: Whats the difference between computed property and function like {{some(prop1)}}

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Whats the difference between defining a computed property and using it like `{{prop}}`

```
prop: {
  type: String,
  computed: 'some(prop1)'
}
```

vs a function binding like

```
{{some(prop1)}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is, as the name implies, also a property of the node object. It can [notify outside listeners](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#notify) or [reflect to attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#attribute-reflection).

Function binding is only used to that. You can call it from the outside but it should have no effect - assuming that the function has no side-effects which is shouldn't.

The most important difference however, is that compute function will evaluate for each binding usage. Computed property will evaluate only once when a dependency changes. See below what happens in the console whenever you click *INCREMENT*.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  properties: {
    i: {
      type: Number,
      value: 0
    },
    c: {
     computed: 'compute(i)' 
    }
  },
  inc: function() {
    console.clear();
    this.i += 1;
  },
  compute: function(i) {
    console.log('computing property binding');
    return i * 2;
  },
  f: function(i) {
    console.log('computing function binding');
    return i * 2;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import" />
</head>

<body>
  <my-elem></my-elem>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <div>Computed: [[c]]</div>
      <div>Computed: [[c]]</div>
      <div>Computed: [[c]]</div>
      <div>Computed: [[c]]</div>
      <div>Function: [[f(i)]]</div>
      <div>Function: [[f(i)]]</div>
      <div>Function: [[f(i)]]</div>
      <div>Function: [[f(i)]]</div>
      <paper-button on-tap="inc">Increment</paper-button>      
    </template>
  </dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmm it seems sometimes function binding works while computed binding does not. It seems like computed binding maybe called earlier or something, causing some other property to be unavailable. But thinking abt it now, I think its my mistake in usage. I should include the property I need in the function arguments, even if it has a default.

Comment: I think you should ask a more specific question :)

Comment: And yes, I think you should place all dependant properties in the compute function (in either case)